# Performance hits modeling polymorphic hasMany relations in one vs many join tables on postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

TL;DR - I'm looking for best-practices feedback on a polymorphic relationship table. Is it better to have a single table without foreign key constraints (making an _id and _type column for each side of the relationship, and an overall type column for the kind of relationship), or is it better to have many tables, one for each kind of possible parent_type - relationship_type - child_type relationship?

I have a couple of tables in my (postgres 9.3) database that have polymorphic relationships. In particular, a `Document` can have access rights granted to both `User` and `Community` type objects (where a `Community` hasMany `User`s as members, so this grants all members of the community that right), where rights include edit, view, and comment.

Right now, I'm modeling this as a single access rights table:

```
CREATE TABLE edges (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    parent_id integer NOT NULL,
    parent_type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    child_id integer NOT NULL,
    child_type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

I have a compound index on this table on the five main columns (parent_type, parent_id, child_id, child_type, type). Naturally, however, my many different kinds of queries often don't hit that main index - sometimes I'm looking for what communities have view rights on this document, more often I'm looking for what documents does this community have view rights on, and quite frequently I have to say, "does this user, or any of the communities that this user is a member of, have view rights on this document".

I also can't really make use of any foreign key constraints that I'd like to be able to. As it stands, I had to write a bunch of triggers to hoke up the kind of behavior I'd get for free from ON DELETE CASCADE. I'd also love stronger protections against (say) deleting non-empty communities or orphaning documents (creating documents where nobody has rights on them at all), which is a lot easier to enforce on single-use tables where I can make stronger claims about referential integrity.

At this point, I'm really optimizing prematurely. My overall database is small, my userbase is not expected to grow past 500 in the next five years. However, I would like to approach this from a best-practices standpoint.

I *could* break that single table up into a ton of smaller tables (user_view_document, user_comment_document, community_view_document, etc - one table per relationship type). That wasn't feasible when I first started this project, because I didn't know how many object types were going to be in the system (which is why there's a parent_type column) or how many permission types would be there either.

I have other edges in the table as well (users can agree / disagree with a document, which is also an edge), but those queries are infrequent enough that I don't mind keeping them all in a single table (because it makes it easier to count how many reactions a document has without referencing likes and agrees and sympathizes, and it also makes it easier to build new kinds of user->document reactions and other edges later), but I'm seriously thinking about pulling the permissions relationships out into their own tables, mainly because the majority of the work my database does right now is calculating access rights on documents using this table.

I could also leave this alone and look at better in-memory cacheing of calculated values (I already use redis to store the list of each user's community memberships, since I end up needing that in every single api lookup, since I keep having to use it in calculating access rights) instead.

So: are there accepted best practices here? Are there good books / blogs / questions to read that will help me get better at optimizing my queries and indexes?

Comment: So `parent_id` and `child_id` are basically foreign keys, pointing to *polimorphic* entities?

Comment: yes, but I can't structurally call them foreign keys, since they may refer to one of several different tables.